# How to sort a dictionary based on different key fields?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains `id,Direction,year,month,day,hour` and I want to sort it based on `month,day,hour`. Below is my dictionary and the values it has:

```
table = {('2339', 'W', '2016', '6', '2', '11'): [0],
         ('2339', 'W', '2016', '1', '16', '8'): [0],
         ('2339', 'W', '2016', '5', '8', '22'): [2],
         ('2339', 'W', '2016', '1', '17', '3'): [0]}
```

and the code I used to sort:

```
    result_dict = sorted(table.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

But this will not sort it the way I want. How can I sort it based on month,day, and hour. The result that I want is look like this:

```
 ID   Direction  year   month  day  hour
2339    W        2016   1       1    0
2339    W        2016   1       1    1
2339    W        2016   1       1    2
2339    W        2016   1       1    3
...     ..      ..      ..      ..   ..
```

Comment: What do you mean by sorting based on month, day and hour? Sorting from most recent to oldest?

Comment: What is the expected structure of `result_dict`? Same as original one but sorted?

Comment: In addition, dictionaries in Python are inherently unordered, so your result will be some other kind of data structure. What kind of result do you want?

Comment: @errata yes same structure as table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ascending order:

```
sorted(table.items(), key=lambda (k,v): map(int, k[3:]))
```

Descending Order:

```
sorted(table.items(), key=lambda (k,v): map(int, k[3:]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the sorting is meant to be lexicographical amongst the values, and ascending in regard to all coordinates, you can take advantage of tuples default sorting, which is lexicographic.

For example:

```
items = [(0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 2), (1, 0, 0)]

s1 = sorted(items)  # [(0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 0)]
s2 = sorted(items, key=lambda t: (t[1], t[2]))  # [(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```

And in the case of the original `table` dictionary:

```
result_dict = sorted(table.items(), key=lambda pair: (int(pair[0][3]),
                                                      int(pair[0][4]),
                                                      int(pair[0][5])))

# [(('2339', 'W', '2016', '1', '16', '8'), [0]),
#  (('2339', 'W', '2016', '1', '17', '3'), [0]),
#  (('2339', 'W', '2016', '5', '8', '22'), [2]),
#  (('2339', 'W', '2016', '6', '2', '11'), [0])]
```

Comment: Why don't you make it into a class and its easy to sort with any field.

Comment: @Tushortz, that's a good idea. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The last four entries in your tuple are already set up in decreasing significance. So just slice them and use the default tuple comparison. Note that you will have to map the strings to integers to compare them properly (otherwise `'10' < '2'`).

```
sorted_keys = sorted(table, key=lambda k: map(int, k[2:]))
print sorted_keys
# [('2339', 'W', '2016', '1', '16', '8'), 
#  ('2339', 'W', '2016', '1', '17', '3'), 
#  ('2339', 'W', '2016', '5', '8', '22'), 
#  ('2339', 'W', '2016', '6', '2', '11')]
```

Then, you can iterate over this set of keys to do whatever you'd like to do.